# Saving a music from the ipod library - swift

Tags: ios, swift, save, mpmediapickercontroller

I'm trying to save a music from the iPod library in my app and be able to use it later. I've used the media picker to get the music URL, but I don't know how to save it in my app and play it later. Here is the code that I have used to get the music URL:

```
@IBAction func music(sender: AnyObject) {
    var picker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: MPMediaType.Music)
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
    picker.prompt =  NSLocalizedString("Select one music", comment: "")
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: false, completion: nil)

}

func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
    var url = NSURL()

    let items = mediaItemCollection.items
    for item in items {
       url = item.assetURL!
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {

   mediaPicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save a music"? 

1. Do you mean that you want save the actual audio file?
2. Do you simply mean that you want to save the persistentID so that you can retrieve it later?

Comment: I want to save the actual audio file so that the app won't rely on the music app later to play it

Comment: Hi, theilya do u find the code?